# Copy Sheet values and conditional formatting while excluding named ranges to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data that I wish to copy all values and conditional formatting from to a worksheet in another workbook. To do this, I have the following working code:

```
wsDestinationSheet.Cells.ClearContents
wsDestinationSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
        
'Copy range from the active sheet to the clipboard ready to paste in the destination sheet
Range("A1:O19").Copy
        

wsDestinationSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wsDestinationSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
wsDestinationSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Some of the columns in the source sheet are goverened by dropdowns and using Paste:=xlPasteFormats not only copies all the conditional formatting but it will also copy the Name Manager definitions. In the first instance it seems fine but when I go to copy it a second time it warns me that there's existing matching Name Manager definitions in the destination sheet which I need to choose to overwrite or use. I don't need the Name Manager definitions in the destination so I was wondering if there's a way to exclude them when copying across the source formatting? I'd like to ensure I copy across all the conditional and value formats.

**Edit 1**

I now have it deleting the entries in the name manager using the following -

```
For i = wbDestinationWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
wbDestinationWorkbook.Names(i).Delete         
Next
```

However, Count is 5, eventhough there are only 4 visible if I inspect the name manager in the destination workbook prior to it running through the delete code. As it runs through from 5 down to 1 it deletes all the entries without issue. However, when it gets to 1 it throws an error. If I inspect wbDestinationWorkbook.Names(1) it shows the value parameter as "=#NAME?" and the name parameter as "_xlfn.XLOOKUP". Is this even a valid name entry in the name manager, and if not, is there a way I can check each name entry is valid before I attempt to delete it?

Comment: You won't be able to change this behaviour. Instead delete the unnecessary names after the copying

Comment: Hi Ike,

I tried deleting the names from the destination workbook, but it throws an error after deleting what seems to be a non existent entry. There's a count of 5 Name entries when I break in the code after the copy but before the name delete, but when I investigate the open destination workbook there's only 4 entries. The code subsequently removes 4 of them and when it gets to i = 1 it throws the error The syntax of the name isn't correct. The code I use is:

`For i = wbDestinationWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
            wbDestinationWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
        Next`

Comment: The value of wbDestinationWorkbook.Names(1) is "=#NAME?" and name is "_xlfn.XLOOKUP". Is this even a valid name entry in the name manager, and if not, is there a way I can check each name entry is valid before I attempt to delete it?

Comment: hmm - I tried to reproduce this - but for me it is possible to delete a name with the mentioned error ...

Comment: Tried sticking the name delete code in the destination workbook and running directly from there but I get the same issue, just doesn't like that last entry.